# Mandar parámetros en función onClick en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quería saber cómo enviar parámetros cuando hago un evento `onClick`. Lo intenté haciendo `onClick={funcionDeEjemplo('texto')}` pero no respeta el `onClick` y se ejecuta cuando se renderiza el componente, además de forma infinita. Pero cuando hago el evento `onClick` normal: `onClick={this.funcionDeEjemplo}`sí que me realiza el evento correctamente.

Comment: Trata de poner tu código de ejemplo, mira, tienes aquí algunas directivas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que buscar en la doc oficial :)

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

Son dos ejemplos equivalentes.

Pero acá te explico un poco más. En React, cuando en un componente usamos las llaves {} lo que coloquemos dentro es una expresión javascript. Esto es, código javascript que será ejecutado.

En el primer ejemplo, estás creando una función anónima que retorna a su vez la función (o método de la clase del componente) deleteRow, que recibe id y e (el evento), donde "id" puede tener el valor que asignes durante la renderización. Ya que es una arrow function, el contexto de "this" es del elemento padre, o sea de la clase/función del componente.

El segundo ejemplo estás ejecutando directamente la función/método deleteRow pero haces un bind, el propósito del bind (que es propio de JS) es cambiar el contexto de la variable "this" al componente de react (mismo resultado que el primer caso pero implementado diferente).

Ya te imaginarás cómo está declarada la función/método deleteRow, algo como:

```
deleteRow (id, e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // do something with id
}
```

Por lo antes dicho, la razón por la que no funciona con el modo en que colocas en tu pregunta, es que no estás bindeando la variable "this". Como dije antes, esto es propio de JS y no tanto de React.

Te sugiero que le des un vistazo a esta [lectura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this), te servirá bastante para subir un nivel más en la programación con React :)

Referencia:

[doc oficial de react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => {
  alert('You clicked me!');
}}>
```

Esto viene explicado en la nueva pagina de React.dev

https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events

de manera rapida dice que hay que evitar llamar la funcion, sino que hay que pasarla, algo asi como un prop, de esta manera no se ejecuta cada que se renderiza el componente sino que cada que hay un evento, en este caso, onClick.

Comment: Esta pregunta fue respondida hace 6 años. Evita reflotar preguntas muy antiguas, más si ya fueron respondidas y el usuario aceptó la respuesta por válida.